# python: split sentence for annotation

Tags: python

lists :

```
matrixA = []
matrixB = []
```

sentences :

```
sentences 1 = "words1 words2 words3 {matrixA} {matrixB}"
sentences 2 = "words3 words4  {matrixA}"
etc..
```

result :

```
matrixA = "words1 words2 words3", "words3 words4"
matrixB = "words1 words2 words3"
etc..
```

any idea, library that support ?
import re, nltk, or ?
can do it manually, but if i use library i think more faster.

Comment: Those aren't arrays....

Comment: sry, i didn't usually use python, but i mean list or kind.. :D

Comment: little update in sentences, then i could use Beautiful Soup, done..

Comment: So, are the variable names always at the end in curly braces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you have many sentences, it would be sensible to put it inside a `list`:

```
sentences = ["words1 words2 words3 {matrixA} {matrixB}", "words3 words4  {matrixA}"]
```

Next, for varying variable names such as `Matrix*`, I'd recommend using a `defaultdict` of lists from the `collections` package.

```
from collections import defaultdict
matrices = defaultdict(list)
```

Now, comes the loop. To get a list of names in each sentence, use `re.findall`. Then, for each variable name found, append the words to the list for that variable name in `matrices`.

```
import re

for s in sentences:
    for m in re.findall("{(.*?)}", s):
        matrices[m].append(s.split('{', 1)[0])
```

```
print(dict(matrices))
{
    "matrixA": [
        "words1 words2 words3 ",
        "words3 words4  "
    ],
    "matrixB": [
        "words1 words2 words3 "
    ]
}
```

Which seems to be what you're looking for.

If you don't want trailing spaces, append `s.split('{', 1)[0].strip()`, calling `str.strip` to get rid of leading/trailing whitespace characters.